# tkinter, integrating an interactive grid into onto a page

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an end goal of creating a battleship game (with a long way to go). To begin I am trying to master having multiple windows with various widgets on them and the ability to switch between windows.

Currently I am trying to get a game board to be on one of the pages that can be clicked on to change colors(the beginnings of what would happen when a player clicked a tile to guess a ship position). However, the board opens detached from my main window and when clicked on it throws the following error:

> File "C:/Users/thani/Desktop/Code/Py_Projects/Boiler_Plate.py", line 109, in 
>       L.bind('', lambda e, i=i, j=j: on_click(i,j,e))
>   NameError: name 'on_click' is not defined

The section of code I am using for the board will work on its own:

```
#import tkinter as tk is at the beginning

board =[ [None]*10 for _ in range(10) ]
counter = 0
root = tk.Tk()

def on_click(i,j,event):
    global counter
    color = "red" if counter % 2 else "black"
    event.widget.config(bg=color)
    board[i][j] = color
    counter += 1

for i, row in enumerate(board):
    for j, column in enumerate(row):
        L = tk.Label(root, text='    ', bg='grey')
        L.grid(row=i, column=j)
        L.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e, i=i, j=j: on_click(i,j,e))

#root.mainloop() is at the end
```

but not when integrated into the page:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Grid_Test(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nesw")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

#Start page and page one omitted as they are not relevant to the issue of pagetwo's grid 

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two")
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        P2button1 = tk.Button(self, text="back to home",
                            command= lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        P2button1.grid(row=1, column=1)
        #P2button1.pack()

    board =[ [None]*10 for _ in range(10) ]
    counter = 0
    root = tk.Tk()

    def on_click(i,j,event):
        global counter
        color = "red" if counter % 2 else "black"
        event.widget.config(bg=color)
        board[i][j] = color
        counter += 1

    for i, row in enumerate(board):
        for j, column in enumerate(row):
            L = tk.Label(root, text='    ', bg='grey')
            L.grid(row=i, column=j)
            L.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e, i=i, j=j: on_click(i,j,e))


app = Grid_Test()
app.geometry("500x500")
app.mainloop()
root.mainloop()
```

so I believe that the issue comes from the fact that the board isn't "in" pagetwo. With this in mind I think I am missing some vital understanding of how widgets work in tkinter.

My question is then how does one integrate a grid into a window?

My full code is here:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Grid_Test(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nesw")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,bg="red")
        label = tk.Label(self, text="start page")
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.grid(row=0, column=1)

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent,bg="white")
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One",bg="blue")
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.create_text()

        P1_button1 = tk.Button(self, text="back to home",
                            command= lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        P1_button1.grid(row=1,column=1)

        P1_button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Continue to page 2",
                               command= lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        P1_button2.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def create_text(self):
        self.textbox = tk.Text(self.master, height=10, width=79, wrap='word')
        vertscroll = tk.Scrollbar(self.master)
        vertscroll.config(command=self.textbox.yview)
        self.textbox.config(yscrollcommand=vertscroll.set)
        self.textbox.grid(column=0, row=0)
        vertscroll.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky='NS')


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two")
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        P2button1 = tk.Button(self, text="back to home",
                            command= lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        P2button1.grid(row=1, column=1)

    board =[ [None]*10 for _ in range(10) ]
    counter = 0
    root = tk.Tk()

    def on_click(i,j,event):
        global counter
        color = "red" if counter % 2 else "black"
        event.widget.config(bg=color)
        board[i][j] = color
        counter += 1

    for i, row in enumerate(board):
        for j, column in enumerate(row):
            L = tk.Label(root, text='    ', bg='grey')
            L.grid(row=i, column=j)
            L.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e, i=i, j=j: on_click(i,j,e))


app = Grid_Test()
app.geometry("500x500")
app.mainloop()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: instead of using `Tk()` for new windows you should used `Topelevel()`. There are several issues I see here and need to be addressed. probably should use class methods and class attributes instead of functions and global variables.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with 'Topelevel()'  I'll look it up. In regards to class methods and class attributes, does using these make it easier to integrate widgets into the window as opposed to using functions and global variables? @Mike-SMT

Comment: Yes they do make it easier and easier to maintain. I am working on a an example right now.

Comment: I added my example. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global variables by definition are not indented at all ... so they can't be part of a class. Also, you need to use instance variables to address things in a class, eg `self.onclick` instead of just `onclick`. Try this:

```
counter = 0
board =[ [None]*10 for _ in range(10) ]
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two")
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        P2button1 = tk.Button(self, text="back to home",
                            command= lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        P2button1.grid(row=1, column=1)

        for i, row in enumerate(board):
            for j, column in enumerate(row):
                L = tk.Label(self, text='    ', bg='grey')
                L.grid(row=i, column=j)
                L.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e, i=i, j=j: self.on_click(i,j,e))

    def on_click(self, i,j,event):
        global counter
        color = "red" if counter % 2 else "black"
        event.widget.config(bg=color)
        board[i][j] = color
        counter += 1
```

You should never have code that's in a class but not part of a method, except in some very rare cases.

I tested it ... it sorta works, but your layout is screwed by the text and Button. You should move the grid to it's own frame:

```
gridframe = tk.Frame(self)
gridframe.grid(columnspan=2)
for i, row in enumerate(board):
    for j, column in enumerate(row):
        L = tk.Label(gridframe, text='    ', bg='grey')
        L.grid(row=i, column=j)
        L.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e, i=i, j=j: self.on_click(i,j,e))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problems I see are generally easy to correct. First you do not ever want to run more than one instance of `Tk()`. In you code your have a class that inherits from `Tk()` and late on `PageTwo` you also try to run a 2nd instance of `Tk()`. This is actually not need and should be removed.

Instead of using some function and trying to work with global's we can instead move the `on_click` function into your class and convert you variables into class attributes. This will allow us to work with the attributes directly without the need of global.

In your `GridTest` class you were using pack() and This can and will cause issues when mixing geometry managers. Instead lets add 2 frames in `PageTwo` and us grid on everything. This way we can set up the top frame for labels and nav buttons and the bottom frame for the grid of the game.

Take a look at the below code and let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk

class GridTest(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("500x500")
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan=10, rowspan=10, sticky="nsew")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nesw")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,bg="red")
        label = tk.Label(self, text="start page")
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.grid(row=0, column=1)

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent,bg="white")
        tk.Label(self, text="Page One",bg="blue").grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.create_text()

        tk.Button(self, text="back to home",
                  command= lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage)).grid(row=1,column=1)
        tk.Button(self, text="Continue to page 2",
                  command= lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo)).grid(row=2, column=1)

    def create_text(self):
        self.textbox = tk.Text(self.master, height=10, width=79, wrap='word')
        vertscroll = tk.Scrollbar(self.master)
        vertscroll.config(command=self.textbox.yview)
        self.textbox.config(yscrollcommand=vertscroll.set)
        self.textbox.grid(column=0, row=0)
        vertscroll.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky='NS')


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        top_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
        bottom_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        bottom_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        tk.Label(top_frame, text="Page Two").grid(row=0,column=0)
        top_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        tk.Button(top_frame, text="back to home",
                  command= lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage)).grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.board =[ [None]*10 for _ in range(10) ]

        self.counter = 0

        for i, row in enumerate(self.board):
            for j, _ in enumerate(row):
                bottom_frame.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
                bottom_frame.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
                L = tk.Label(bottom_frame, text='    ', bg='grey')
                L.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky="nsew")
                L.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e, i=i, j=j: self.on_click(i,j,e))

    def on_click(self, i,j,event):
        color = "red" if self.counter % 2 else "black"
        event.widget.config(bg=color)
        self.board[i][j] = color
        self.counter += 1


app = GridTest()
app.mainloop()
```

The results is a PageTwo that has your game grid and it can resize with the window.

[image]